# angularjs directive isolated scope within link method

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

My jsbin is here: http://jsbin.com/yapi/1/edit

I am testing the isolated scope within link method of the directive (it works when used within template instead).

My goal is that link method in different directives to be able to share and change same data (by reference, not by value). So that if a link method in one directive changes the data then it gets reflected in link method in other directives.

However, it does not seem to work as you can see in the jsbin link. e.g. if you change Dir 1 it does not change Dir 2 and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would use Angular's pub/sub pattern

[Here is an article the talks about best practices](http://eburley.github.io/2013/01/31/angularjs-watch-pub-sub-best-practices.html)

I would have a bunch of directives that interact with there own scope data,
when data changes in a directive it can $broadcast('message', data) a change to that data
other directives can listen $on('message', function(data){})

If you want everything to rely on the same data, then just use a service (singleton) that all the directive interact with